# Failure at MySQL Source > error code 0xC02090F5

Tags: ssis

I am encountering problem with SSIS package that I am developing. I am migrating from MySQL to SQL Server. My Source fails after retreiving around 30000+ records.

From help found on net I put a RowCount component and found that the data flow completes without any issues at source.

My Destination is on a Different Server. MySQL Source and SSIS package is on my development.

The error code that I am getting is
The PrimeOutput method on component "ADO NET Source" (123) returned error code 0xC02090F5.

I have made no of records in Buffer to :20000

command timeout is :300

My thinking ( and it is only guess here) is that the delay in writing records to destination is causing the issue. Is there anything to speed it up.

[image]

Comment: Please don't write tags in titles / sign your posts

Comment: Thank you for removing the tag from the title

Comment: If your Data flow looked like nothing but "Prepare Customer Lo..." and a row count transformation, the package would complete successfully? If that's the case, then I'd look at your ADO.NET Destination as the culprit. Yes, source is red but I have seen scenarios where the destination failed for things like PK violation but the source gets marked as the failure. You might also check your script component. Turn on logging & log OnError, OnWarning, OnTaskFailed and OnInformation and make sure there isn't anything "hidden" in there. Otherwise, turn on SQL Profiler and capture statements

Comment: @Billinc- If I break the source into two parts by where condition, I get the data written to Destination. I will turn on Logging ( new to ssis to need to check how to) and may be I will have additional information for you all looking into this issue.

Comment: Add a new dataflow and make it look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/laffl.png) Use the same query/table you have in the failing dataflow. If that dataflow runs to completion, then you know the problem is with somewhere downstream. Otherwise, you know there is a problem in the source data.

Comment: @Billinc - I already did mention  in my question that it does work with Row Count Component ( I replaced ADO NET Destination with this Component with a user variable to hold value). Is there a way to dump record as it comes to sqlserver. May be there is too much type checking going on in execute phase?